# adding search bar through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a working search bar that is added through the html. However to make the code unobtrusive i am trying to append the search bar and button through JavaScript. I am able to display the search bar and button, but the functionality of bringing up results has stopped working.

Here is the section to add the search bar in JS.

```
var $searchSection = $('<div class="student-search"></div>');
$searchSection.append('<input id = "search-criteria" placeholder="Search for students..."></input>');
$searchSection.append('<button>Search</button>');

//Append search section
$('.page-header').append($searchSection);
```

I am trying to get the functionality of search working. Here is a link to the code with the search working, as the search bar is included in the html. http://codepen.io/fun/pen/RRyaNm

This is a link to the code with search bar added through the js but with no search functionality. http://codepen.io/fun/pen/VjraNd?editors=1010

How do you get the search to work through adding from the js?

Any help or pointers would be awesome.

Thank you,

Harry

Comment: `$('#search-criteria');` doesn't exist at the time you're fetching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add more function, just move your codes to the top. Check this 
jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xt5193z1/

```
//Search section

var $searchSection = $('<div class="student-search"></div>');
$searchSection.append('<input id = "search-criteria" placeholder="Search for students..."></input>');
$searchSection.append('<button>Search</button>');

//Append search section
$('.page-header').append($searchSection);


var $studentItem = $('.student-item');
var $pagination = $('.pagination');
var $searchCriteria = $('#search-criteria');
var perPage = 10;


// count number of student items
var studentCount = $studentItem.length;
// number of pages = number of students / 10 rounded up
var pageNumber = Math.ceil(studentCount / perPage);
// remove all student items
var initialTen = $studentItem.hide();
// display first 10 student items
initialTen = $studentItem.slice(0, perPage).show();
// pagination ul
var paginationHTML = '<ul>';
// calc number of links
for (var i = 1; i < pageNumber + 1; i++) {
  // li and link for each page
  paginationHTML += '<li><a href ="#">' + i + '</a></li>';
}
// end of ul
paginationHTML += '</ul>';
// display list to page
$pagination.html(paginationHTML);
// pagination link click
$('.pagination li a').on('click', function() {
  // remove active
  $('.pagination li a.active').removeClass('active');
  // add active class
  $(this).addClass('active');
  // page number of clicked
  var pageNum = this.text;
  // Start point for slice
  // e.g 3 * 10
  var startFrom = pageNum * perPage - perPage;
  // end point for slice
  // e.g 30 + 10
  var endOn = startFrom + perPage;
  // display students based on number clicked
  $studentItem.hide().slice(startFrom, endOn).show();

});





// Error message for no matches found
var $noMatches = $('<h2>No matches found please try again</h2>');
// Add to page
$('.page').append($noMatches);
// hide initially
$noMatches.hide();

// search box on type
$searchCriteria.on('input', function() {
  // remove all result classes
  $studentItem.each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("result");
  });

  // value of searched
  var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  // results of search  
  var results = $("ul.student-list li:contains('" + text.toLowerCase() + "')");
  results.addClass("result");
  // show or hide based on result matching div
  $studentItem.each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('result')) {
      $(this).show("slow");
    } else {
      $(this).hide();

    }

  });

  if (results.length > 10) {

    // remove all student items
    var initialTen = $studentItem.hide();
    // display first 10 student items
    initialTen = $studentItem.slice(0, perPage).show();
    // show pagination
    $('.pagination').show();
    // hide no matches message
    $noMatches.hide();
  } else if (results.length === 0) {
    $pagination.hide();
    $noMatches.show();

  } else {
    $pagination.hide();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

As Siguza said, `$('#search-criteria')` doesn't exist at the time you're fetching it. So, the `on` function is a good idea, but it should be given like this :

```
$('.page-header').on('input', '#search-criteria', function() {
     //your code
});
```

What it does is , it will bind the function to the element that is added dynamically in DOM

Here is the [jsFiidle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxL41dsm/)

It will work for you. :)

Comment: Nicely done, it works well thank you. Event delegation always gets me!

Comment: @hjb-webdesign Happy to help :)